# SharePoint Online daily checklist form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

how to SharePoint Online daily checklist form just like on the screen?
[image]

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: If question is about creating a form like this there are various ways. For simplicity you may use HTML controls with css and Javascript. Use JSOM functions for getting current user etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions to extend SharePoint online for this requirement.

Create custom HTML form so you could CRUD SharePoint list data either with JSOM/rest api, front-end framework(angular etc.) would help you achieve this [demo thread](http://sids-blogsite.blogspot.com/2016/02/crud-operations-on-sharepoint-list.html) more easily.

Or SPFx solution for modern experience [demo](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud).